# "Hiding" a system call from ltrace and strace

Tags: shell, system-calls

Is there a way to hide a system call from `strace` and a dynamic library call from `ltrace`? For example, the use of `system` (`<stdlib.h>`).

In the last class for my software construction this semester, the instructor revealed to us that we could have gotten away with using the `system` library function call in many parts of the command shell project we were assigned instead of the more complicated `fork`, `exec`, `readdir`, `stat`, `dup`, and `pipe` system calls we were told to use.

The way `system` works, he said, is you simply pass in a string of the command you want to execute: `system("cmd [flags] [args]; cmd && cmd");` and there you are.

We *were not supposed to* use this function, but he said he didn't check our programs for it. One way to hide its use would have been to obscure it through Macro definitions and such. However, `ltrace` is still able to track `system` down when used through Macros. I believe it  even finds it when its called from a separate program, like `execvp( "./prgrm_with_system", ...).

My chance to use it is gone, but I am really curious about whether there is a way to hide `system` from even `ltrace`.

Comment: Despite the name, `system` is not a system call, and is not related to system calls. It's just a library function to fork and run `sh` to interpret the string as a command. You can avoid it showing up in `ltrace` by duplicating that functionality so it's not called as a library function, but you can't hide the fork+execve from `strace`.

Comment: Hiding from `ltrace` is easy -- just inline the behavior. Hiding from `strace` is a different matter. Really, they're different enough that they shouldn't even be the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`system()` doesn't do anything that's magic. It doesn't even do anything that's *smart* (and using it is often a code smell). It also isn't a system call in the sense that the term "syscall" refers to.

You could trivially create your own version of `system()` using the underlying syscalls `fork()` and `execve()`, and bypass detection with `ltrace`... but `strace` would still show those calls happening.

You *also* could bypass `ltrace` with static linking, but since syscalls are by definition for things that require the OS kernel's help, you can't do without them entirely -- so tools such as strace, sysdig, truss, dtrace, and local equivalents can't be so easily avoided (without exploiting security vulnerabilities in the OS or the tools themselves).

Comment: Note that there is more to `system()` than just `fork()` and `exec*()`.  [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) says: _The system() function shall ignore the SIGINT and SIGQUIT signals, and shall block the SIGCHLD signal, while waiting for the command to terminate. ...

The `system()` function shall not affect the termination status of any child of the calling processes other than the process or processes it itself creates.
The `system()` function shall not return until the child process has terminated._ This requires non-negligible signal handling.

Comment: @Charles, thank you for you insightful answer. If I understand correctly, I could create a basic duplicate of `system` by making a call to `fork()` and running something like `execvp("/bin/sh -c", args)`, where `args[1]` has a string of the command that needs be executed? Could you expand on your example of static linking a bit? Is there a tool similar to `ltrace` which detects the use of `system`?

Comment: @Jinzo, in the case of static linking with sufficiently aggressive inlining, no such tool is even theoretically possible. `strace` can't be defeated absent bugs, but `ltrace` is impossible to implement in a manner which succeeds when faced with determined evasion requests.

Comment: @Jinzo, ...re: the example you gave, by the way, `execlp("/bin/sh", "-c", args, (char*)0)` is closer; the `-c` must be a separate argument.

Comment: @Jinzo, re: static linking, see the `ltrace` man page: "It intercepts and records the dynamic library calls which are called by the executed process and the signals which are received by  that  process" -- with a statically linked binary, there *are* no dynamic library calls.